# FtpClient and FtpWebRequest — what's the difference?

Tags: ftpwebrequest

I have used the FtpClient to connect to the FTP Server,Upload a file and download a file from the FTP server.
I found FtpWebRequest which does the same functionality as of FtpClient.

Could anyone please let me know the difference between these two.
And which is the best to use.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

there is many tools in FtpClient and you can use it easily, by the way FtpClient is using  FtpWebRequest. 
FtpWebRequest  is better for advanced user